# SIrange with leading plus

Tags: siunitx

When using `siunitx`, by default, `\SIrange{-4}{+6}{\percent}` will render

> -4% to 6%.

Is there any general way to change rendering of the positive values with a leading "+" for the positive values?

> -4% to +6%

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 22):

This is controlled by option `retain-explicit-plus`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  \SIrange[retain-explicit-plus]{-4}{+6}{\percent}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The option can also be set via `\sisetup`.

### Fonts

There are many options that control the fonts that are used. Examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  \SIrange[retain-explicit-plus]{-4}{+6}{\percent}

  \textbf{%
    \SIrange[
      detect-weight,% or detect-all
      retain-explicit-plus,
    ]{-4}{+6}{\percent}%
  }%

  \textit{%
    \SIrange[
      mode=text,
      detect-shape,% or detect-all
      retain-explicit-plus,
    ]{-4}{+6}{\percent}%
  }%

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: perfect, thank you! Ist it possible to format thist text? I want to use it in a table. \bfseries{...} or \mathbf{...} didn't work.